# Mongo: is it the same to use .find({_id: id}) vs .findOne({_id: id})?

Tags: mongodb, optimization, mongoose

I'm asking this question performance wise - knowing that there is a unique document with `id`.

```
MyCollection.find({_id: id}) //this should return only one document - id is unique
```

vs

```
MyCollection.findOne({_id: id}) //this is equivalent to .find({_id: id}).limit(1) from what I've read
```

My first thought is that no matter the filter, the `.find` has to go through the collection thus the `.findOne` is faster in the case I just want to retrieve one doc, am I correct? Or maybe since `_id` is always indexed, maybe there is no difference?

I'm not asking about the output of the functions, this is an optimization/perf question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find() and findOne() methods in MongoDB showing different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40168478/find-and-findone-methods-in-mongodb-showing-different-results)

Comment: @kRiZ my question is about the performance, not on the output of the functions.

Comment: May be this gives very clear about the performance. Your question had been already tried and dusted over the site for long time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33156703/whats-faster-find-limit1-or-findone-in-mongodb-mongoose

Comment: This is also a different question, I want to know if calling `.find` (**without** `.limit(1)` but knowing that it should return one element) is faster/slower/same as calling `.findOne()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, there's no performance difference (because of the unique index, yes).

There may be response shape differences. I'm not familiar with mongoose, but in mongodb shell, `find()` returns a cursor (which is enumerated right away) and `findOne()` returns the document directly.

Comment: So there is no difference as soon as the filter contains only indexed fields that would return 1 result?

Comment: It the Mongo shell, `findOne` also pretty-prints the result.

Comment: The only real difference is that `findOne` also specifies `limit(1)`. But if you only have single document you can possibly hit anyway, I cannot imagine that this matters at all. (it would matter if you had many potential hits).